# How to simulate pumping well in SEAWAT using flopy with a salinity constrain?

Tags: flopy

I want to simulate a pumping well above seawater intrusion in SEAWAT using flopy and want to cease automaticly pumping when the salinity concentration in the well's cell reaches to a certain level, for example, 5% of relative salinity. In other words, I want the well extract only freshwater and when the the saltwater starts increasing in the well (due to up-coning), stop pumping. I really appreciate it if someone helps me to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once. What you could do is write and run your model for every separate day (for example) and use the starting head and concentrations from the previous day as input for the current day. You can check whether the concentrations near your well exceed your threshold and then decide if your well is going to extract that day.